# How do I update the value of text when I hold an button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update the value of a counter when I hold a button in my react app. However I am encountering a problem where the couunter isn't being updated unless I spam click the button. I expect to be able to hold the button to have the counter to increment as the amount of time I hold the button increase.

Here is a example of what I am truing to do:

```js
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [rpm, setRpm] = useState("");
  const [rpmTxt, setRpmText] = useState("");
  const [interval, setIntervalID] = useState(NaN);
  const [isHoldingButton, setHoldingButton] = useState(false);
  
  useRef(() => {
    setRpmText("RPM: " + timeHeld);
  }, [rpm]);
  
  function onButtonHold() {
    if (isHoldingButton)
      return;
    setHoldingButton(true)
    setIntervalID(setInterval(() => {
      setRpm(rpm + 50);
    }, 50))
  }
  
  function onButtonRelease() {
    setHoldingButton(false)
    clearInterval(interval)
  }
  
  return (
    <div id="app">
      <button onPointerDown={onButtonHold} onPointerUp={onButtonRelease}>Button hold</button>
      <p>{timeHeldText}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
        
ReactDOM.(<App />, document.getElementByID("root"));

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

I tried to use a `useRef` hook to keep the timout id however it didn't worked out as the `useRef` property is immutable therefore can't be changed.

```js
function App() {
  const [rpm, setRpm] = useState("");
  const [rpmTxt, setRpmText] = useState("");
  const intervalIdRef = useRef(null)
  const [isHoldingButton, setHoldingButton] = useState(false);

  
  useRef(() => {
    setRpmText("RPM: " + timeHeld);
  }, [rpm]);
  
  function onButtonHold() {
    if (isHoldingButton)
      return;
    setHoldingButton(true)
    intervalIdRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setRpm(rpm + 50);
    }, 50)
  }
  
  function onButtonRelease() {
    setHoldingButton(false)
    clearInterval(intervalIdRef.current)
  }
  
  return (
    <div id="app">
      <button onPointerDown={onButtonHold} onPointerUp={onButtonRelease}>Button hold</button>
      <p>{timeHeldText}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
        
ReactDOM.(<App />, document.getElementByID("root"));

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Comment: The function onButtonHold will return before executing code. You write `return;` just after the if. Either encapsulate the rest of the code and do `if (isHoldingButton) return handleHold()`or add curlybraces and only write return before interValIdref.current = balbla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
function App() {
  const [rpm, setRpm] = useState(0);
  const [interval, setIntervalID] = useState(NaN);
  const [isHoldingButton, setHoldingButton] = useState(false);

  const getRpmText = () => "RPM: " + rpm;

  function onButtonHold() {
    if (isHoldingButton)
      return;
    setHoldingButton(true)
    let value = 0;
    setIntervalID(setInterval(() => {
      setRpm(value += 50);
    }, 50))
  }

  function onButtonRelease() {
    setHoldingButton(false)
    clearInterval(interval)
    setRpm(0);
  }

  return (
    <div id="app">
      <button onPointerDown={onButtonHold} onPointerUp={onButtonRelease}>Button hold</button>
      <p>{getRpmText()}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```